# I am unable to read the only emails in the form of array

Tags: php, arrays

I have one array. That array assign to one variable but i am unable to read only emails in that array.That array in given below.

```
$users = array(3) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#404 (4) { ["guid"]=> string(1) "2" ["name"]=> string(13) "xyz" ["username"]=> string(13) "xyz" ["email"]=> string(23) "xyz@gmail.com" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#405 (4) { ["guid"]=> string(3) "138" ["name"]=> string(12) "wxyz" ["username"]=> string(5) "wxyz" ["email"]=> string(21) "wxyz@gmail.com" } [2]=> object(stdClass)#406 (4) { ["guid"]=> string(3) "126" ["name"]=> string(13) "xxxx" ["username"]=> string(7) "xxxx" ["email"]=> string(17) "xxxx@gmail.com" } }
```

I need ouput like that

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(22) "xyz@gmail.com" [1]=> string(19) "wxyz@gmail.com"  [3]=> string(19) "xxxx@gmail.com"}
```

Please give me reply.Advance thank you very much.

Comment: Google: `PHP array_map()`

Comment: Thank you vey much sir, for giving information on above issue. i have code like that                                                                                           
         foreach($users as $user)
 {
  $to_name = $user->name;
  if($user->name == '')
  {
  $to_name = $user->username;
  }
 $to_email = $user->email;
 
 }

Comment: How read the emails in the form of like that array(3) { [0]=> string(22) "xyz@gmail.com" [1]=> string(19) "wxyz@gmail.com" [3]=> string(19) "xxxx@gmail.com"} . In above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use an `array_walk` function over here like as

```
$result = [];
array_walk($users,function($v,$k)use(&$result){
    $result[$k] = $v->email;
});
```

Using `array_map`

```
$result = array_map(function($v){return $v->email;},$arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `preg_grep()` to return particular pattern only from an array.

```
preg_grep( "your Pattern", $array);
```

Check sample below

```
$email_only_array = preg_grep("/^[A-z0-9_\-]+[@][A-z0-9_\-]+([.][A-z0-9_\-]+)+[A-z.]{2,4}$/", $your_array);
```

Example:

```
// Your array
$array = array("john","wxyz","aaa@mail.com", "wxyz", "bbb@mail.com", "ccc@mail.com");
   // validating the value as array     
$email_only_array = preg_grep("/^[A-z0-9_\-]+[@][A-z0-9_\-]+([.][A-z0-9_\-]+)+[A-z.]{2,4}$/", $array);    
   // Output
print_r($email_only_array);
```

Output

```
Array ( [2] => aaa@mail.com [4] => bbb@mail.com [5] => ccc@mail.com )
```

Refer this also, http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php

Comment: Thank you very much sir. i tried above code i passed the array like $users in given pattern, , but it gives empty array sir. Please give me reply sir.

Comment: Thank you vey much sir, for giving reply on the issue. I tried in my code, it' working fine sir.i am able to retrieve the only emails in the form of array.Thank you sir.